# How to group datatable items

Tags: jquery, datatable, grouping

I'm working on a jquery datatable which needs to group data by a column. I'm using mysql query to retrieve data to the datatable and my datatable looks as below.

```
From        To          Marks
2017-01-04  2017-10-10  0.16
2017-10-11  2017-12-31  0.43
2018-1-1    2018-12-31  0.12
2019-1-1    2019-10-15  0.10
2019-10-16  2019-12-31  0.39
2020-1-1    2020-02-04  2.94
```

I need this data table to look as below

```
From        To          Marks
2017
2017-01-04  2017-10-10  0.16
2017-10-11  2017-12-31  0.43

2018
2018-1-1    2018-12-31  0.12

2019
2019-1-1    2019-10-15  0.10
2019-10-16  2019-12-31  0.39

2020
2020-1-1    2020-02-04  2.94
```

My code segment to create first datatable which I have given above:

```
function setEmployeeTbl(emp) {
    $.each(emp, function (i, employee) {
    $('#tblEmployee > tbody:last-child').append('<tr id="' + employee.id + '">'
        + '<td > ' + employee.from + '</td>'
        + '<td > ' + employee.to + '</td>'
        + '<td > ' + employee.marks + '</td>'
        + '</tr>');
    });
    $("#tblEmployee").DataTable({
        "searching": false,
    });
}
```

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you try your code, does it work? If not, what does it say and what do you want it to do?

Comment: @PrimuS My code gives the output as the first table I posted above. But what I want is to get the output as the 2nd table I have posted which is I need to group all my data by the year only.